# Re-using an existing interface as a WCF Interface. Does contract decoration affect existing applications? Is there any harm?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, interface

I have a scenario where I have an existing interface that I would like the WCF service to implement.

The main goal is to allow us to be able to use dependency injection such that the implementation can be injected as a WCF service or a local assembly.

E.g.

**Existing interface**

```
public interface IStuffDoer
{
   bool DoStuff(string parameter);
}
```

Now I need a WCF Service contract of type `IStuffDoer`. An option that I can think of is

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStuffDoerService: IStuffDoer
{

}
```

But then note that the existing interface does not have its operations decorated by either `[ServiceContract]` or `[OperationContract]` attributes.

---

Since one cannot override parent interface method signatures, my only option(as far as I know) is decorating the original interface with WCF contract attributes, like so:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStuffDoer
{
   [OperationContract]
   bool DoStuff(string parameter);
}
```

**Is there any harm in doing so?**

**What is the impact on existing, non-WCF applications or that are making use of that contract?**

**If it impacts them somehow, what would be my best option?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the impact on existing, non-WCF applications or that are making use of that contract?

There is not impact. It's still the same interface. The attributes don't do anything on their own. You can decorate your interface with them and still use it as a "normal" interface.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt.  Do you happen to have any references on something authoritative? Otherwise, I would take your word for it. Not doubting your expertise

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any sources but my own experience. I don't think you will find any reference listing what is *not* harmful. That list would be endless.

Comment: very well then. Thank-you. Marking it as an answer... until someone "authoritatively" disputes it :)

Comment: @user919426 there is a drawback in that any in-process consumers will need knowledge of System.ServiceModel etc in order to consume.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tom. Though I did this over a year ago and it worked for my purposes, would you please expand on that?

Comment: @user919426 well, if a consumer simply wants to use your domain models by directly referencing the assembly, they will need to be minumum .net3.0. Additionally they could not be used in other situations eg office/sharepoint/SQLCLR development because of the lack of support for WCF. However, these are all edge cases and may not be of concern.

Comment: @tomredfern For some reason, I don't think I got to read your comment... so even if it's 3years later, it's still helpful...and thanks!